# How to Normalize Frequency in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, frequency

I know all about conversion of frequency from HZ to normalized frequency and from normalized frequency to angular frequency ,but I wonder how it is done in MATLAB.
I have the following code:

```
f:0:0.001:1;
omega=pi*f
```

here f=normalized frequency and omega=angular frequency. My question is how do we get the interval value(0.001) for our normalized frequncy.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This should answer your question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15219/convert-normalized-frequency-to-real-frequency-in-ar-model/15220#15220

Comment: Thanks for the link.But acctually my question is how do we go about deciding the interval valu.in this case it is 0.001 why not 0.002?

Comment: @Lakshmi, Could you please review my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The interval resolution should be determined according to data you want to analyze.

It is equivalent to the question, what magnification of your Micro Scope would you use?
Well, it depends on the size of the things I want to look at.

If your data within the sampling frequency you set has different energy in each frequency bin and you'd like to see it, use small intervals.

Though,
The real question, how do you intend to use the Frequency Vector?